# Open VPN packets aren't going through tunnel

Tags: linux, network-interface, openvpn, vpn, tunneling

```
port 1194 
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 0
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

This is the server conf file i have used

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ********* 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
key-direction 1
cipher AES-128-CBC
redirect-gateway def1
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

This the client conf file i have used

While sending the packets to the server they're not going through the tunnel.
I have used traceroute to check the path between the client and server,the packets are taking another way.
Should I modify or add any commands to the conf files so that i can make the packets go through tunnel?

Comment: Are your routes configured correctly? Check `ip route`

Comment: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to {ServerIP}' 
               iptables -I INPUT -p {proto} --dport {port} -j ACCEPT'
               iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT'
               iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT'
               

These are the iprules at the server side